# Why latex is slow in building a .tex file?

Tags: packages

I have a .csv file which contains 796 rows and 20 columns, it tooks more than 15 minutes to build the file which I am reading the file from .csv, can we do something to build fast to get the same results. I am using the packages `graphicx`,`booktabs`,`xstring`,`datatool`,`xintexpr`,`longtable`,`minted`,`multirow`,`colortbl`,`tcolorbox` and `xcolor`. Your comments is so precious. I could not write all the lines in the csv file.Thanking you. Here is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[10.0pt,legalpaper,landscape]{article}
 \usepackage[top=0.5cm,bottom=1.4cm,left=2cm,right=0.1cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,xstring,datatool,xintexpr,longtable,minted} %for including eps graphics
 \usepackage{multirow,colortbl}
 \usepackage{filecontents} 


 \renewcommand{\dtldisplaystarttab}{\toprule}
 \renewcommand{\dtldisplayafterhead}{\midrule}
 \renewcommand{\dtldisplayendtab}{\\\bottomrule}

 \usepackage{array}
 \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
 \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

 \begin{filecontents*}{MemberSummary.csv}
      Unique ID,Name,Gender,Blood Group,Relationship with Head,Date of Birth,Baptised,Date of Baptism,Baptized By,Death,Date of Death,Transfer,Date of Transfer,Phone No.,Suspension,Reason,Areawise,Educational Qualification,Ocupation,Youth,Women,Signature
 ABC0001,Name 1,M,AB+,Head,03/05/1933,Y,19/06/1946,Baptized 1,N,,N,,1234567895,,,Area 3,Cl-X,Retd. G.Sw,Y,Y,
 ,Name 2,F,AB+,Wife,,Y,17/07/1960,Baptized 2,N,,N,,1234567896,,,Area 3,,House wife,N,N,
 ,Name 3,M,AB+,son,,Y,26/02/1980,Baptized 3,N,,N,,1234567897,,,Area 3,Cl-X,,N,N,
 ,Name 4,F,AB+,Daughter in law,,Y,27/06/1985,Baptized 4,N,,N,,1234567898,,,Area 3,Cl-VIII,House Wife,Y,Y,
 ,Name 5,F,AB+,Grand Daughter,,N,,Baptized 5,N,,N,,1234567899,,,Area 3,Cl-II,Student,Y,Y,
 ,Name 6,F,AB+,daughter ,,Y,,Baptized 6,N,,Y,,1234567900,,,Area 3,,,Y,Y,
 ,Name 7,M,AB+,Son,,Y,06/04/94,Baptized 7,N,,N,,1234567901,,,Area 3,B.A,Music Teacher,Y,Y,
 ,Name 8,M,A+,Son,,Y,30/04/1996 ,Baptized 8,N,,N,,1234567902,,,Area 3,B.A,Office Asst.,Y,Y,
 ABC0002,Name 9,F,A-,Head,,Y,17/04/1990 ,Baptized 9,N,,N,,1234567903,,,Area 4,Matriculate,Service,Y,Y,
 ,Name 10,M,A-,Father,,Y,,Baptized 10,Y,02/12/2007,,,1234567904,,,Area 4,,,Y,Y,
 ,Name 11,M,A-,Son ,,Y,11/06/08,Baptized 11,N,,N,,1234567905,,,Area 4,H.S. Passed,Student,Y,Y,
 ,Name 12,M,A-,Son ,,Y,,Baptized 12,N,,N,,1234567906,,,Area 4,Cl-VIII,Student,Y,Y,
 ABC0003     ,Name 13,M,A-,Head,,Y,,Baptized 13,N,,N,,1234567907,,,Area 1,Matriculate,Service,Y,Y,
 ,Name 14,F,A-,Wife,,Y,,Baptized 14,N,,N,,1234567908,,,Area 1,Graduate,Teacher,Y,Y,
 ,Name 15,F,A-,Daughter,,Y,,Baptized 15,N,,N,,1234567909,,,Area 1,Cl-IX,Student,Y,Y,
 ABC0004,Name 16,M,A-,Head,,Y,1935,Baptized 16,N,,N,,1234567910,,,Area 2,Cl-X,Retired,Y,Y,
 ,Name 17,M,A-,Father,,Y,,Baptized 17,Y,died ,,,1234567911,,,Area 2,,,Y,Y,
 ,Name 18,F,A-,Mother,,Y,,Baptized 18,Y,died ,,,1234567912,,,Area 2,,,Y,Y,
 ,Name 19,F,A-,Wife,,Y,,Baptized 19,N,,N,,1234567913,,,Area 2,,House wife,Y,Y,
 ,Name 20,M,A-,Son,,Y,,Baptized 20,,,,,1234567914,Y,,Area 2,M.A pol.sc,Business,Y,Y,
 ,Name 21,F,A-,Daughter in Law,,Y,,Baptized 21,N,,N,,1234567915,,,Area 2,Under Graduate,Service,Y,Y,
 ,Name 22,M,A-,Grand son,,Y,,Baptized 22,N,,N,,1234567916,,,Area 2,M.A,Student,N,N,
 ,Name 23,M,A-,Grand son,,Y,,Baptized 23,N,,N,,1234567917,,,Area 2,B.A,Student,N,N,
 ,Name 24,F,A-,daughter ,,Y,,Baptized 24,,,,,1234567918,Y,,Area 2,,,N,N,
 ,Name 25,F,A-,Daughter in Law,,Y,,Baptized 25,N,,Y,,1234567919,,,Area 2,Under Graduate,Srevice,N,N,
 ABC0005,Name 26,M,AB+,Head,,Y,,Baptized 26,N,,N,,1234567920,,,Area 5,Graduate,Business,N,N,
 ,Name 27,F,A+,Wife,,Y,,Baptized 27,N,,N,,1234567921,,,Area 5,"M.A, B.ed",Lecturer,N,N,
 ,Name 28,F,A+,Daughter,,N,,Baptized 28,N,,N,,1234567922,,,Area 5,Student,Student,N,N,
 ,Name 29,F,B+,Daughter,,N,,Baptized 29,N,,N,,1234567923,,,Area 5,,,N,N,
 ,Name 30,M,B+,Son,,N,,Baptized 30,N,,N,,1234567924,,,Area 5,,,N,N,
 ABC0006,Name 31,F,B+,Head ,,Y,,Baptized 31,N,,N,,1234567925,,,Area 3,Cl-VII,House wife,N,N,
 ,Name 32,M,B+,Father,,Y,,Baptized 32,Y,22-1-2014,,,1234567926,,,Area 3,Cl-VII,Business,N,N,
 ,Name 33,M,B+,Son,,Y,,Baptized 33,N,,N,,1234567927,,,Area 3,Cl-X,,N,N,
 ,Name 34,F,B+,Daughter,,Y,,Baptized 34,N,,N,,1234567928,,,Area 3,Matriculate,,Y,Y,
 ,Name 35,F,B+,daughter ,,Y,,Baptized 35,N,,Y,,1234567929,,,Area 3,,,N,N,
 ABC0007,Name 36,M,O-,Head,,Y,,Baptized 36,N,,N,,1234567930,,,Area 6,B.A,Bussiness,Y,Y,
 ,Name 37,F,O+,Wife,,Y,,Baptized 37,N,,N,,1234567931,,,Area 6,,House wife,Y,Y,
 ,Name 38,M,B-,Son,,Y,,Baptized 38,N,,N,,1234567932,,,Area 6,H.S. Passed,,Y,Y,
 ,Name 39,F,O-,Daughter in law,,Y,,Baptized 39,N,,N,,1234567933,,,Area 6,Cl-X,,Y,Y,
 ,Name 40,F,O+,grand daughter ,,N,,Baptized 40,N,,N,,1234567934,,,Area 6,,,Y,Y,
 ,Name 41,M,O+,Son ,,Y,,Baptized 41,N,,N,,1234567935,,,Area 6,H.S. Passed,,Y,Y,
 ,Name 42,M,O+,Son,,N,,Baptized 42,N,,N,,1234567936,,,Area 6,Cl-VII,,Y,Y,     
 \end{filecontents*}

 % read in text file to database
 \DTLloaddb{death}{MemberSummary.csv}


 % set up counters
 \newcounter{Female}   % Female Membership Counter
 \newcounter{Male}     % Male Membership Counter
 \newcounter{FemaleD}  % Female Death counter
 \newcounter{MaleD}    % Male Death counter
 \newcounter{Total}    % Total Membership counter
 \newcounter{TotalD}   % Total Death counter
 \newcounter{MaleB}    % Baptised Male counter
 \newcounter{FemaleB}  % Baptised female counter
 \newcounter{MaleU}    % UnBaptised Male counter
 \newcounter{FemaleU}  % UnBaptised female counter
 \newcounter{TotalU}   % Total Unbaptised Member counter
 \newcounter{TotalB}   % Total Baptised counter
 \newcounter{MaleT}    % Total male transfer
 \newcounter{FemaleT}  % Total female transfer
 \newcounter{TotalT}   % Total transfer
 \newcounter{MaleE}    % Existing male members
 \newcounter{FemaleE}  % Existing female members
 \newcounter{TotalE}    % Existing total members
 \newcounter{MaleBE}   % Existing male baptised
 \newcounter{FemaleBE} % Existing female baptised
 \newcounter{TotalBE}  % Existing total baptised
 %\newcounter{SerialI}   % Serial Numbering Iteration according to name present
 \newcounter{Serial}   % Serial Numbering according to name present
 \newcounter{SerialN}   % Serial Numbering 
 \newcounter{A}         % Coding for Area 1
 \newcounter{B}         % Coding for Area 2
 \newcounter{C}         % Coding for Area 3
 \newcounter{D}         % Coding for Area 4
 \newcounter{E}         % Coding for Area 5
 \newcounter{F}         % Coding for Area 6
 \newcounter{AT}         % Coding for Area 1 total members
 \newcounter{BT}         % Coding for Area 2 total members
 \newcounter{CT}         % Coding for Area 3 total members
 \newcounter{DT}         % Coding for Area 4 total members
 \newcounter{ET}         % Coding for Area 5 total members
 \newcounter{FT}         % Coding for Area 6 total members
 \newcounter{AreaT}      % Total areawise members
 \newcounter{AH}         % Coding for Area 1 Total Household 
 \newcounter{BH}         % Coding for Area 2 Total Household 
 \newcounter{CH}         % Coding for Area 3 Total Household 
 \newcounter{DH}         % Coding for Area 4 Total Household
 \newcounter{EH}         % Coding for Area 5 Total Household
 \newcounter{FH}         % Coding for Area 6 Total Household
 %%%%
 \newcounter{GA}         % Coding for Area 1
 \newcounter{GB}         % Coding for Area 2
 \newcounter{GC}         % Coding for Area 3
 \newcounter{GD}         % Coding for Area 4
 \newcounter{GE}         % Coding for Area 5
 \newcounter{GF}         % Coding for Area 6
 \newcounter{GAH}         % Coding for Area 1 household
 \newcounter{GBH}         % Coding for Area 2 household
 \newcounter{GCH}         % Coding for Area 3 household
 \newcounter{GDH}         % Coding for Area 4 household
 \newcounter{GEH}         % Coding for Area 5 household
 \newcounter{GFH}         % Coding for Area 6 household
 \newcounter{TotalG}     % Counter for total existing member
 \newcounter{TotalGH}    % Counter for total house existing
 \newcounter{TotalUE}    % counter for existing unbaptise
 \newcounter{TotalUME}   % counter for unbaptised existing male
 \newcounter{TotalUFE}   % counter for unbaptised existing female 
 \newcounter{FSus}       % counter for female suspension
 \newcounter{MSus}       % counter for male suspension
 \newcounter{TotalSus}   % counter fot total suspension
 %% Counter for blood group
 \newcounter{Ap}         % counter for blood group A+
 \newcounter{Am}         % counter for blood group A+
 \newcounter{Bp}         % counter for blood group B+
 \newcounter{Bm}         % counter for blood group B-
 \newcounter{Op}         % counter for blood group O+
 \newcounter{Om}         % counter for blood group O-
 \newcounter{ABp}         % counter for blood group AB+
 \newcounter{ABm}         % counter for blood group AB-
 \newcounter{BloodT}    % counter for total blood group
 \makeatletter\let\expandableinput\@@input\makeatother 

 \begin{document}
 %\DeclareTCBListing{mybox}{ s O{} m }{%
  %colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,IfBooleanTF={#1}{listing side text}{text side listing},title=#3,#2}
 \DeclareTColorBox{mybox}{ o }{colframe=white,colback=gray!15!white,
 IfValueTF={#1}{title={\flqq #1\frqq},fonttitle=\bfseries}{}}

 %\arrayrulewidth=0.7pt % change thickness of vertical and horizontal lines of a table
 \begin{longtable}{|C{0.5cm}|C{1.5cm}|L{4.7cm}|C{0.35cm}|C{1.8cm}|C{0.6cm}|C{0.35cm}|C{1.8cm}|L{4.1cm}|C{0.35cm}|C{1.8cm}|C{0.3cm}|C{1.8cm}|l|C{3.7cm}|}
 %\toprule
 \hline
 \rowcolor{green!20}\bf\rotatebox{90}{Sl.~No.} & \bf{Unique ID} & \hfill\bf{Name}\hfill~ & \bf\rotatebox{90}{Gender}& \bf{Date\newline of\newline Birth}& \bf\rotatebox{90}{Blood Group} & \bf\rotatebox{90}{Baptised}&\bf{Date\newline of\newline Baptism} & \hfill\bf{Baptized By}\hfill~ & \bf\rotatebox{90}{Death}& \bf{Date\newline of\newline Death} & \bf\rotatebox{90}{Transfer}& \bf\rotatebox{90}{Phone No.} & \bf{\hspace{6mm}Areawise} & \bf{Signature}\\\hline \endhead

 \DTLforeach*{death}{\id=Unique ID,\name=Name,\g=Gender,\bg=Blood Group,\d=Death,\b=Baptised,\tr=Transfer,\phone=Phone No.,\a=Areawise,\DOB=Date of Birth,\DOBap=Date of Baptism,\by=Baptized By,\DOD=Date of Death}{% build table
 \DTLiffirstrow{}{\\\hline} %
 % add \midrule before first data row
 %\DTLiffirstrow{\\\midrule\endhead}{\\} 
 %
 \IfStrEq{\g}{F}{% check if female
   \stepcounter{Female}% add 1 to counter
   \IfStrEq{\d}{Y}{\stepcounter{FemaleD}}{}% if also dead, add 1 to that counter
 }{%
   \stepcounter{Male}% similar for male
   \IfStrEq{\d}{Y}{\stepcounter{MaleD}}{}%
 }%

 \IfStrEq{\g}{F}{% check if female

   \IfStrEq{\b}{Y}{\stepcounter{FemaleB}}{\stepcounter{FemaleU}}% if also dead, add 1 to that counter
 }{%

   \IfStrEq{\b}{Y}{\stepcounter{MaleB}}{\stepcounter{MaleU}}%
 }%

 \IfStrEq{\g}{F}{% check if female

   \IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{Y}{\stepcounter{FemaleT}}}{}% if also dead, add 1 to that counter
 }{%

   \IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{Y}{\stepcounter{MaleT}}}{}%
 }%


 \IfStrEq{\g}{F}{\IfStrEq{\b}{Y}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\stepcounter{FemaleBE}}{}}{}}{}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\g}{M}{\IfStrEq{\b}{Y}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\stepcounter{MaleBE}}{}}{}}{}}{}

 \IfStrEq{\a}{Area 1}{\stepcounter{A}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\a}{Area 2}{\stepcounter{B}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\a}{Area 3}{\stepcounter{C}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\a}{Area 4}{\stepcounter{D}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\a}{Area 5}{\stepcounter{E}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\a}{Area 6}{\stepcounter{F}}{}

 %% Coding for Areawise Total Household
 \IfStrEq{\a}{Area 1}{\IfBeginWith{\id}{ABC}{\stepcounter{AH}}{}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\a}{Area 2}{\IfBeginWith{\id}{ABC}{\stepcounter{BH}}{}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\a}{Area 3}{\IfBeginWith{\id}{ABC}{\stepcounter{CH}}{}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\a}{Area 4}{\IfBeginWith{\id}{ABC}{\stepcounter{DH}}{}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\a}{Area 5}{\IfBeginWith{\id}{ABC}{\stepcounter{EH}}{}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\a}{Area 6}{\IfBeginWith{\id}{ABC}{\stepcounter{FH}}{}}{}


 \IfSubStr{\id}{ABC}{\stepcounter{Serial}}{}
 %\setcounter{Serial}{\numexpr\value{SerialI}\relax}
 %\IfInteger{\theSerial}{\stepcounter{SerialNo}}{}
 \IfInteger{\theSerial}{\stepcounter{SerialN}}{}


 \IfStrEq{\d}{Y}{\IfInteger{\theSerial}{\noindent\raise.5em\vbox{\cellcolor{red!20}\theSerialN} & \cellcolor{red!20}\id & \cellcolor{red!20}\name & \cellcolor{red!20}\g & \cellcolor{red!20}\DOB & \cellcolor{red!20}\bg & \cellcolor{red!20}\b & \cellcolor{red!20}\DOBap & \cellcolor{red!20}\by & \cellcolor{red!20}\d & \cellcolor{red!20}\DOD & \cellcolor{red!20}\tr & \cellcolor{red!20}\phone & \cellcolor{red!20}\a & \cellcolor{red!20}  }{}}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{Y}{\IfInteger{\theSerial}{\noindent\raise.5em\vbox{\cellcolor{blue!20}\theSerialN} & \cellcolor{blue!20}\id & \cellcolor{blue!20}\name & \cellcolor{blue!20}\g & \cellcolor{blue!20}\DOB & \cellcolor{blue!20}\bg & \cellcolor{blue!20}\b & \cellcolor{blue!20}\DOBap & \cellcolor{blue!20}\by & \cellcolor{blue!20}\d & \cellcolor{blue!20}\DOD & \cellcolor{blue!20}\tr & \cellcolor{blue!20}\phone & \cellcolor{blue!20}\a & \cellcolor{blue!20} }{}}{\IfInteger{\theSerial}{
 \noindent\raise.5em\vbox{\theSerialN} & \id & \name & \g &\DOB & \bg & \b &\DOBap & \by & \d &\DOD & \tr & \phone & \a & }{}}}
 }
 \\\hline


 \end{longtable}

 %\end{center}
 %\end{minipage}
 %\begin{minipage}{5mm}
 %\end{minipage}\hfill\hfill
 \newpage

 \pagenumbering{gobble}
 %\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,pagesize}
 %\recalctypearea
 %% Coding for existing household and existing members
 \DTLforeach*{death}{\id=Unique ID,\name=Name,\g=Gender,\bg=Blood Group,\d=Death,\b=Baptised,\tr=Transfer,\a=Areawise, \s=Suspension}{
 %% Set values for area existing member

 %%set values for existing members
 \IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area 1}{\stepcounter{GA}}{}}{}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area 2}{\stepcounter{GB}}{}}{}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area 3}{\stepcounter{GC}}{}}{}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area 4}{\stepcounter{GD}}{}}{}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area 5}{\stepcounter{GE}}{}}{}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area 6}{\stepcounter{GF}}{}}{}}{}
 %%set values for existing household number of each areawise
 \IfStrEq{\id}{}{}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area 1}{\stepcounter{GAH}}{}}{}}{}}
 \IfStrEq{\id}{}{}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area 2}{\stepcounter{GBH}}{}}{}}{}}
 \IfStrEq{\id}{}{}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area 3}{\stepcounter{GCH}}{}}{}}{}}
 \IfStrEq{\id}{}{}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area 4}{\stepcounter{GDH}}{}}{}}{}}
 \IfStrEq{\id}{}{}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area 5}{\stepcounter{GEH}}{}}{}}{}}
 \IfStrEq{\id}{}{}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area 6}{\stepcounter{GFH}}{}}{}}{}}
 %% set values for suspension from church
 \IfStrEq{\g}{F}{\IfStrEq{\s}{Y}{\stepcounter{FSus}}{}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\g}{M}{\IfStrEq{\s}{Y}{\stepcounter{MSus}}{}}{}
 %% set values for blood group members
 \IfStrEq{\s}{Y}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{A+}{\stepcounter{Ap}}{}}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{A+}{\stepcounter{Ap}}{}}{}}{} }
 \IfStrEq{\s}{Y}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{A-}{\stepcounter{Am}}{}}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{A-}{\stepcounter{Am}}{}}{}}{} }
 \IfStrEq{\s}{Y}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{B+}{\stepcounter{Bp}}{}}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{B+}{\stepcounter{Bp}}{}}{}}{} }
 \IfStrEq{\s}{Y}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{B-}{\stepcounter{Bm}}{}}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{B-}{\stepcounter{Bm}}{}}{}}{} }
 \IfStrEq{\s}{Y}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{O+}{\stepcounter{Op}}{}}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{O+}{\stepcounter{Op}}{}}{}}{} }
 \IfStrEq{\s}{Y}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{O-}{\stepcounter{Om}}{}}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{O-}{\stepcounter{Om}}{}}{}}{} }
 \IfStrEq{\s}{Y}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{AB+}{\stepcounter{ABp}}{}}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{AB+}{\stepcounter{ABp}}{}}{}}{} }
 \IfStrEq{\s}{Y}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{AB-}{\stepcounter{ABm}}{}}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\bg}{AB-}{\stepcounter{ABm}}{}}{}}{} }
 }

 % set total values
 \setcounter{TotalB}{\numexpr\value{FemaleB}+\value{MaleB}\relax}
 \setcounter{TotalU}{\numexpr\value{FemaleU}+\value{MaleU}\relax}
 % set total values for alive and death members
 \setcounter{Total}{\numexpr\value{Female}+\value{Male}\relax}
 \setcounter{TotalD}{\numexpr\value{FemaleD}+\value{MaleD}\relax}
 % set total values for transfer members
 \setcounter{TotalT}{\numexpr\value{FemaleT}+\value{MaleT}\relax}
 % set values for existing members
 \setcounter{MaleE}{\numexpr\value{Male}-\value{MaleT}-\value{MaleD}\relax}
 \setcounter{FemaleE}{\numexpr\value{Female}-\value{FemaleT}-\value{FemaleD}\relax}
 \setcounter{TotalE}{\numexpr\value{MaleE}+\value{FemaleE}\relax}
 % set values for existing baptised members
 \setcounter{TotalBE}{\numexpr\value{FemaleBE}+\value{MaleBE}\relax}

 % set values for areawise
 \setcounter{AT}{\numexpr\value{A}\relax}
 \setcounter{BT}{\numexpr\value{B}\relax}
 \setcounter{CT}{\numexpr\value{C}\relax}
 \setcounter{DT}{\numexpr\value{D}\relax}
 \setcounter{ET}{\numexpr\value{E}\relax}
 \setcounter{FT}{\numexpr\value{F}\relax}
 \setcounter{AreaT}{\numexpr\value{A}+\value{B}+\value{C}+\value{D}+\value{E}+\value{F}\relax}

 \setcounter{TotalG}{\numexpr\value{GA}+\value{GB}+\value{GC}+\value{GD}+\value{GE}+\value{GF}\relax}
 \setcounter{TotalGH}{\numexpr\value{GAH}+\value{GBH}+\value{GCH}+\value{GDH}+\value{GEH}+\value{GFH}\relax}
 \setcounter{TotalUME}{\numexpr\value{MaleE}-\value{MaleBE}\relax}
 \setcounter{TotalUFE}{\numexpr\value{FemaleE}-\value{FemaleBE}\relax}
 \setcounter{TotalUE}{\numexpr\value{TotalUME}+\value{TotalUFE}\relax}

 % Total for suspension
 \setcounter{TotalSus}{\numexpr\value{FSus}+\value{MSus}\relax}

 % Total blood group for existing members
 \setcounter{BloodT}{\numexpr\value{Ap}+\value{Am}+\value{Bp}+\value{Bm}+\value{Op}+\value{Om}+\value{ABp}+\value{ABm}\relax}

 \bigskip

 \vspace*{3mm}
 \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!80!white, colframe=red!75!black, rounded corners, halign=center] 
 \color{white}\LARGE\fontsize{185}{185}\bfseries\section*{\MakeUppercase{ABC membership summary}}
 \end{tcolorbox} 

 %\tcbset{enhanced,colback=blue!80!white,colframe=yellow!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,frame code app={\path[tcb fill frame]
 %([yshift=-2mm]frame.north)circle (8mm); } }
 %\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\LARGE \bfseries \hfill ~ABC \hfill~]
 %\color{white}\LARGE\bfseries\section*{\MakeUppercase{\hfill membership summary\hfill~}}
 %\end{tcolorbox}



 \bigskip

 \vspace{10mm}
 \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,arc=3mm,boxrule=1.5mm,frame hidden,colback=blue!10!white,borderline={1mm}{0mm}{blue,dotted} ]
 % print results for all members
 \hspace*{5mm}\begin{minipage}{5mm}
 \begin{tabular}{llr}
 Male Membership   &: & \theMale \\
 Female Membership &: & \theFemale \\
 \bottomrule
 \it Total            & : & \theTotal \\
 &&\\
 No. of Male Unbaptised     & : & \theMaleU \\
 No. of Female Unbaptised   & : & \theFemaleU\\
 \bottomrule
 \it Total            & : & \theTotalU \\
 && \\
 Male Baptised   & : & \theMaleB \\
 Female Baptised & : & \theFemaleB \\
 \bottomrule
 \it Total   & : & \theTotalB
 \end{tabular}
 \end{minipage}\hfill
 \begin{minipage}{5mm}
 \begin{tabular}{llllr}
 No. of Male Death   & & &: & \theMaleD \\
 No. of Female Death & &&: & \theFemaleD\\
 \bottomrule
 \it Total    &  && : & \theTotalD \\
 &&&&\\
 Male Transfers   &&& : & \theMaleT\\
 Female Transfers &&& : & \theFemaleT\\
 \bottomrule
 \it Total  &&&: & \theTotalT
 \end{tabular}
 \end{minipage}\hfill
 \hspace*{-10mm}\begin{minipage}{5mm}
 \begin{tabular}{llcc}
 \toprule
 {\bf Areawise   }       &   & {\bf Household} & {\bf Members}\\ \midrule
 Area 1  & : & \theAH          & \theA \\
 Area 2     & : & \theBH          & \theB \\
 Area 3  & : & \theCH          & \theC  \\
 Area 4  & : & \theDH          & \theD \\
 Area 5    & : & \theEH          & \theE \\
 Area 6  & : & \theFH          & \theF \\
 \bottomrule
 \it Total  & : & \theSerial           & \theAreaT
 \end{tabular}
 \end{minipage}\hfill~
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \bigskip

 %\begin{minipage}{5mm}
 %% print results for death members
 %\begin{tabular}{llllr}
 %No. of Male Death   & & &\hspace{1mm}: & \theMaleD \\
 %No. of Female Death & &&\hspace{1mm}: & \theFemaleD\\
 %\bottomrule
 %\it Total    &  &&\hspace{-0.07mm} : & \theTotalD 
 %\end{tabular}
 %\end{minipage}\hfill\hfill
 %\begin{minipage}{5mm}
 %% print results for unbaptised member
 %\end{minipage}\hfill\hfill
 %\begin{minipage}{5mm}
 %\begin{tabular}{llr}
 %Male Transfers   & : & \theMaleT\\
 %Female Transfers & : & \theFemaleT\\
 %\bottomrule
 %\it Total  &: & \theTotalT
 %\end{tabular}
 %\end{minipage}\hfill\hfill~

 \bigskip

 \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,arc=3mm,boxrule=1.5mm,frame hidden,colback=green!10!white,borderline={1mm}{0mm}{green,dotted} ]

 \bigskip

 %\begin{mybox}[\hfill Existing Members \hfill]{}
 \hspace*{5mm}\begin{minipage}{5mm}
 \begin{tabular}{llr}
 Existing Male   & : & \theMaleE\\
 Existing Female & : & \theFemaleE\\
 \bottomrule
 \it Total  &: & \theTotalE \\
 &&\\
 Existing Baptised Male & : & \theMaleBE\\
 Existing Baptised Female & : & \theFemaleBE\\
 \bottomrule
 \it Total  & : & \theTotalBE\\
 &&\\
 Unbaptised Existing Male & : & \theTotalUME \\
 Unbaptised Existing Female & : & \theTotalUFE\\
 \bottomrule
 \it Total  & :& \theTotalUE
 \end{tabular}
 \end{minipage}\hfill
 \begin{minipage}{5mm}
 \begin{tabular}{lcc}
 \toprule
 {\bf Blood Group} & &{\bf Members}\\ \midrule
 \hspace*{9mm} A+  & : & \theAp \\
 \hspace*{9mm} A~-  & : & \theAm \\
 \hspace*{9mm} B+  & : & \theBp \\
 \hspace*{9mm} B~-  & : & \theBm \\
 \hspace*{9mm} O+  & : & \theOp \\
 \hspace*{9mm} O~-  & : & \theOm \\
 \hspace*{7mm} AB+  & : & \theABp \\
 \hspace*{7mm} AB~-  & : & \theABm \\
 \bottomrule
 \it \hfill~~~ Total \hfill~ & : & \theBloodT
 \end{tabular}
 \end{minipage}\hfill
 \hspace*{-10mm}\begin{minipage}{5mm}
 \begin{tabular}{llcc}
 \toprule
 {\bf Areawise   }       &   & {\bf Household} & {\bf Members}\\ \midrule
 Area 1  & : & \theGAH          & \theGA \\
 Area 2     & : & \theGBH          & \theGB \\
 Area 3  & : & \theGCH          & \theGC  \\
 Area 4  & : & \theGDH          & \theGD \\
 Area 5    & : & \theGEH          & \theGE \\
 Area 6  & : & \theGFH          & \theGF \\
 \bottomrule
 \it Total & : & \theTotalGH          & \theTotalG \\
 &&&\\
 Female Suspension&:&  &\theFSus \\
 Male Suspension&:&  &\theMSus \\
 \bottomrule
 \it Total &:&  &\theTotalSus \\
 \end{tabular}
 \end{minipage}\hfill~
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: What are you subsequently doing with the contents of the csv file?  As always, a MWE helps.

Comment: i will upload MWE prepairing the format. @HenriMenke

Comment: This code is far from minimal.  You are a member for over two years with over 30 questions! -1

Comment: Also for me this example takes 1 second to compile.

Comment: What could be the reason for taking too much time for compilation @HenriMenke

Comment: @BikiTeron I have no idea.  You are not providing a minimal example to reproduce.

Comment: The code i have given above is the code that i am compiling @HenriMenke

Comment: @BikiTeron If this exact example is extremely slow on your PC, then you need a better PC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59094/discussion-between-biki-teron-and-henri-menke).

Comment: why have you included minted here which forces anyone trying to help to risk `-shell-escape` on untrusted code?

Comment: Have you read section 6.11.2 of the [datatool user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf)? "The `\DTLforeach` command described in Section 6.4 has some limitations, especially when trying to iterate through large databases. This section describes lower-level user commands that may be used for iteration instead of `\DTLforeach`."

Answer (score 5):

As posted (on a 3 year old laptop) I get typical times of

```
real    0m7.695s
user    0m5.013s
sys     0m2.650s
```

If I increase it to over 800 rows then it takes

```
real    24m42.629s
user    24m38.998s
sys     0m2.636s
```

which is pretty slow by modern standards although the coding style with `DTLloaddb` and `\IfStrEq` is clearly rather inefficient and not intended for large sets.

This is not an intrinsic problem with the speed of TeX, for example every time a lualatex or xelatex format is built, the file UnicodeData.txt is read for upper/lower case mappings and other information
that is over 29 thousand rows each with 15 `;` separated fields and it only takes a second or so to parse with tex, and assign the relevant `\lccodes` etc.

it appears that the loop you are using is (at least) quadratic so if you make the input 10 times longer it takes 100 times longer to run. Since you only seem to be totalling certain fields it should be possible to make it have time linear in the size of the input.

---

For comparison the file below takes less than 2 seconds

```
real    0m1.780s
user    0m1.250s
sys     0m0.515s
```

To process an 800 line file of the format that you showed

```
$ wc -l MemberSummary.csv
800 MemberSummary.csv
```

Producing 22 pages looking like

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{longtable}

\def\gloop#1\repeat{\gdef\iterate{#1\relax\expandafter\iterate\fi}%
  \iterate \let\iterate\relax}

\newread\zz
\openin\zz=MemberSummary.csv
\begin{document}

{\catcode`\,=\catcode`\& % make comma a table separator

\read\zz to \hdline

\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\setlength\LTleft{-5cm}
\setlength\LTright{-5cm plus 1fil}
\begin{longtable}{lllllllllllllllllllllll}
%  \hdline
 \endhead
\gloop
\ifeof\zz\else
 \read\zz to \tmp\tmp\\
\repeat
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to make coding for linear@David Carlisle

Comment: Kindly let me know which commands will be suitable for large data input to get the same output@David Carlisle

Comment: @BikiTeron your question isn't really suitable for recoding it there is no description of the input or desired output just hundreds of lines of code that do something I do not intend to reverse engineer what the code is doing.  I might add a simple version that just makes a table without all the filtering later.

Comment: Your coding is fast to print the table of 800 lines, how do i select particular colums to print with lines after row by row and for column also @DavidCarlisle

Comment: I don't​ want to print all the column but want to print selected columns, so please help me in that case so to get printing​ fast@David Carlisle